# Google form RegEx validation that matches all numbers and ranges

Tags: regex, google-forms

In my Google form I would like to authorize numbers and range of numbers like this:

```
1 to 9,
10 to 80,
90,
100
```

The separator can be , | ; or newline character, other examples

```
100
110 to 115
540
```

or

```
50 | 60 | 70 to 80 | 100
```

I was expecting this regEx to work (selecting Regular Expression > Matches > (to)|[0-9 \n|,;]*) but it failed.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `^\d+(?:(?:\s*(?:to|[|;,])\s*)\d+)*$`

Comment: It works like a charm ! The  only minor comment is the potential newline at the end.

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow a newline? Or prevent it from appearing? If you want to allow a trailing newline, use `\n*` or `\n?` before `$`.

Comment: In fact newline can also be a separator I can have 10 to 50 newline 60 newline 70 to 80 newline

Comment: Would [`^\d+(?: *(?:to|[|,;])?\n? *\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/4XoiH7/1) work for you? Not sure if I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: `\s` matches line breaks, too. I added `\n` into the character class to match LF chars.

Comment: Close to the solution. I just want to allow empty lines (you know sometimes on the last line you press enter and you have a last empty line). Something like that: ^\d+(?: *(?:to|[|,;])?\n? *\d+\n?)*$    ??

Comment: Did not refresh the page. I see now your final regEx and the explanation. Thanks a lot fir this, appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d+(?:(?:\s*(?:to|[\n|;,])\s*)\d+)*\n*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPSYuy/3). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s*(?:to|[|;,])\s*\d+)*` - zero or more occurrences of

  - `\s*(?:to|[\n|;,])\s*` - `to` or `|`, `;`, `,` or newline enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
  - `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\n*` - zero or more newlines
- `$` - end of string.